# Setting data for multiple UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have two UIPickerViews With data being pulled from an array though I can't seem to program them separately. Here is the code that I am using for my UIPickerViews:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [treatments count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      return[[treatments objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"treatmentName"];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    _buttonText.text = [[treatments objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"treatmentName"];
    if (![_buttonText.text isEqual: @"Pick a Treatment Name"]) {
        _buttonText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)nursePicker:(UIPickerView *)nursePicker numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [nurses count];
}

- (NSString *)nursePicker:(UIPickerView *)nursePicker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return[[nurses objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"nurseName"];
}
```

When I run the code the pickers show the same data

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: The same data is shown in both

Comment: Which data is in both UIDatePickers?(Nurses or Treatment)

Comment: They aren't datepickers they are just UIpickers and the Treatment data is in both

Comment: That is probably due to the fact that they are in an order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store a reference to your two picker views and use the UIPickerView that is passed as an argument to the datasource methods in order to determine which picker view you are using.

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView == self.nursePicker) {
        return [nurses count];
    }
    else if (pickerView == self.treatmentPicker) {
        return [treatments count];
    }
}
```

Same idea for every datasource method

Comment: Thanks that put me on the right track to fix it. I had to do that with all of them

Answer (score 0):

You should put a BOOL to check the data. Create a BOOL called treatment and when the first picker is available set the BOOL to YES and when the second is available set the BOOL to NO. Then check in your methods to see which picker is their and put in the data.

```
@interface NotesViewController ()
{
    BOOL treatment; 
}

- (void)firstPickerComesUP
{
    treatment = YES;
} 

- (void)secondPickerComesUP
{
    treatment = NO;
}
```

Comment: Sorry though I am quite new to ios programming